# Do not add new line in Styled Components with Prettier

Tags: javascript, format, newline, styled-components, prettier

I am using React with Styled Components while formatting code using Prettier. Let's have the following code:

```
const Component = Styled.div`
    color: green;

    ${props => props.important && `
        font-weight: bold;
    `}
`
```

It's simple styled component with usage `<Component />` or `<Component important={true} />`. However, when I format code using Prettier, the code changes to:

```
const Component = Styled.div`
    color: green;

    ${props =>
        props.important &&
        `
        font-weight: bold;
    `}
`
```

Is there any way to set Prettier to not add newline after `=>` and after `&&` in this case? I searched in [Prettier options](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html), however I did not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find the option to do it [here](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuc0DOMAEBhCBbAB2gSwF5MBlGATwBs4ATAOgYEsA3AAwB0pN-MkWhABOSTAHMRcBAG5evAZgAkwAiIgE0mUgD5M6zWiatComAENYmAGQ3MPPkoEAzaDAC0AdzisJACxhxACMIWgZ5J35OAF9eThAAGhBNGFZ0ZFALEQ0vAAVshDRkEAtaLwtqYuTgkQswAGs4GAoCetYoCWQYEQBXOGS4PGDGBkYAGSsJXosJOAAxUTwLGDTOkotemAgkkEC8WgB1f1Z4NDawOAoi045T6hKwNGqQDrQ4ERg8uoll5Bcyu9kgArNAADwAQnVGs0KBY8HBxh04P9AQMQKCwRQOhJ6ABFXoQeCo2hAkBtETvEQlYIWEa0XbqDowQ6sBgwfzIAAcAAZkoZ3oc6gQSuo4FT2CjkgBHQnwb5GDZoDxQGRjBi7aSy1jSb6zP5IAGk9HvPCsbp9E04-FylGGtHJSzBVnszlIABMjrqrFoONweANIHFAFZdr13gAVOnFe3G5LsfoASSgY1gFDAIlYBBgAEEU1Q6Haje8YjEgA) then it isn't possible.

[By design - Prettier is not intended to provide a lot of configuration options.](https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html)